# Creating a compound trigger using .NEW keyword

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am having trouble creating a Trigger in Oracle 11 using Toad Datapoint 4. I am attempting to create a compound trigger.

However, whenever I execute the Create statement for the trigger TOAD asks me to bind variables to all of the

```
:NEW.Id;
:NEW.Audit_Field1;
```

columns. and fails with illegal variable assignment name. I am just trying to perform a single insert statement using this trigger. How can I create this trigger?

```
CREATE TABLE ETRAT.SKU_Override 
( 
            Id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
          Audit_Field1 varchar(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
          Audit_Field2 TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
          Audit_Field3 VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
          Audit_Field4 VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
          Char_Field5 char(1)
);

ALTER TABLE ETRAT.SKU_OVERRIDE ADD 
CONSTRAINT IX_SKU_OVERRIDE_PK PRIMARY KEY (Id);


CREATE TABLE ETRAT.SKU_OVERRIDE_HIST
( 
          Id NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
          Audit_Field1 varchar(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
          Audit_Field2 TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
          Audit_Field3 VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
          Audit_Field4 VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
          Char_Field5 char(1),
      Action varchar(10)
);
commit;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SKU_OVERRIDE_HIST
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON ETRAT.SKU_Override
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE t_emp_changes       IS TABLE OF ETRAT.SKU_OVERRIDE_HIST%ROWTYPE INDEX BY SIMPLE_INTEGER;
  v_emp_changes            t_emp_changes;
  v_index                  SIMPLE_INTEGER       := 0;
  v_threshhold    CONSTANT SIMPLE_INTEGER       := 1000; --maximum number of rows to write in one go.
  v_user          VARCHAR2(50); --logged in user

  PROCEDURE flush_logs
  IS
    v_updates       CONSTANT SIMPLE_INTEGER := v_emp_changes.count();
  BEGIN
    FORALL v_count IN 1..v_updates
        INSERT INTO SKU_OVERRIDE_HIST VALUES v_emp_changes(v_count);
    v_emp_changes.delete();
    v_index := 0; --resetting threshold for next bulk-insert.
  END flush_logs;

  AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
      IF INSERTING THEN
        v_index := v_index + 1;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Id               := :NEW.Id;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Audit_Field1     := :NEW.Audit_Field1;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Audit_Field2     := :NEW.Audit_Field2;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Audit_Field3     := :NEW.Audit_Field3;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Audit_Field4     := :NEW.Audit_Field4;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Char_Field5      := :NEW.Char_Field5;
        v_emp_changes(v_index).Action := 'INSERT';
      ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        v_index := v_index + 1;

        v_emp_changes(v_index).Action := 'UPDATE';
      ELSE 
        v_index := v_index + 1;

        v_emp_changes(v_index).Action := 'DELETE';
END IF;

   END AFTER EACH ROW;

  -- AFTER STATEMENT Section:
  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
     flush_logs();
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

END SKU_OVERRIDE_HIST;
/

INSERT INTO ETRAT.SKU_OVERRIDE
(Id, AUDIT_FIELD1, AUDIT_FIELD2, AUDIT_FIELD3, AUDIT_FIELD4, CHAR_FIELD5)
VALUES (2, 'AUDIT_FIELD1',  null, 'AUDIT_FIE','AUDIT_FIELD', 'C');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What you've posted is fine, so this seems to be an issue with your client - presumably it's parsing the code itself and doesn't understand the trigger syntax. This has come up before with other clients. Try running your code in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer instead.

Comment: Issue is with Toad datapoint 4.0, I had to turn off the variable binding, and even when I did so it still throws an error, however the statement will execute correctly. I was really pulling my hair out over that one.